# Buttons are displayed before the api loads inside the table and loader not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a page where an `api` loads slowly and only two buttons are displayed in my page for some seconds so I have decided to add loader in that page I have tried the below code but the loader is loaded not the page table

```
import Loader from '../Loader/Loader';
const FileTable = () => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
        const handleLoading = () => {
         setIsVisible(false);
        }
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("load",handleLoading);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("load",handleLoading)
    },[])
    return !isVisible ? (
           <div>
             My component
           </div>
    ):(
        <div>
           <h1>Loading...</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FileTable;
```

I even tried the below code

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
```

and then

```
if(!isVisible){
 return <>Loading</>
}

return(
<>
   My Component
</>
)
```

I have tried both the ways but the loader is not working. The buttons should also hide when the page loads only the loader should be displayed until the api loads
How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Your code doesn't have enough information to figure out what you are doing wrong. If possible, paste the entire component

Comment: Where is your API call made? Where is the load event handler definition? I also strongly believe that you are relying on the wrong event

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straightforward scenario would be:

- Initialize your component loading state to **true**
- On component mount, initialize API call
- After API call, set component loading state to false
- Your component should, based on the loading state, render either a loader or the retrieved data from the API call

A sample code would be as the following:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]); // or whatever
  const handleClose = () => {
      setLoading(false)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
      // Init API call here
      // then( ..... setApiData()) // Do whatever with API response to set component apiData
      // finally (() => setLoading(false))
  }, []) // empty dependency array is equivalent to componentDidMount

  if(loading) {
    return <Loader />
  }
  return <Component data={apiData} />
}
```

It is also a good practice to handle eventual API call failures

Comment: tried the above code. buttons are displayed before the api loads inside the table

Comment: manage a state for data and check its validity on ui. Also do check that you setloader after api is done with the result.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.